# How to automate Vim's native auto-completion with a drop-down menu?

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion

*I know there is a ton of plugins and topics that discussing about auto-completion things in Vim!*

I just need the Vim's native auto-completion to be automated!

- auto-suggestion words, etc from buffers' cache.
- auto-suggestion for path.

I've found vim can show a auto-suggestion drop-down menu when I pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> after a word or path. Is there any `autocmd` or a block of code to add in `$VIMRC`to automate this process?

*If it's impossible or there is no such way, so please introduce a plug-in that can just automate this process (not adding any other features!)*

Comment: [VimCompletesMe](https://github.com/ajh17/VimCompletesMe) is quite simple and might do what you want.

Comment: There are tons of plugins already. I'd suggest looking at [deoplete.nvim](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) if you're using neovim. (If you're not using neovim, well then switch to it.)

Comment: Also, I don't use any automation completion manager. I find the automatic pop up distracting. Might be worth noting.